# How can I set a different log level for a Custom Gradle Plugin

Tags: logging, gradle, flyway

I'm writing a flyway wrapper plugin for gradle.
Flyway already uses log4j for it's message logging.

On the info level all the output is relevant to the user.

When I add the custom plugin to new project and run one of its tasks than nothing is displayed in the output. I have to run gradle `flywayStatus` --info to see the messages.

Is there a way to change the log4j settings in the plugin so that the log level does not need to be modified in the projects that use the plugin?

Any idea would really be appreciated.

Thanks,
Gerwin

Comment: Flyway 1.8 uses either standard out or commons-logging. You should be able to easily write a Gradle adapter for its internal logging abstraction. See the Maven and Ant plugins for examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to the [LoggingManager](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/logging/LoggingManager.html) for the task by calling its getLogging() method.

You can set the logging level on the Manager.